# Como usar AuthStateListener() firebase

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

He estado investigando dado que cuando borro un usuario desde la pantalla autenticación de firebase y luego me meto en la app desde la app que tengo en el telefono de prueba, el usuario sigue apareciendo como autentificado. Para solucionar esto busque por internet y me encontre con el Authstatelistener() y como no entendía como funcionaba busque como aplicarlo, abajo os dejo el ejemplo. Ahora me aparece un error que me dice que no se puede resolver el simbolo mAuthlistener. ¿Alguien sabría como solucionarlo?

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAuthlistner = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                updateUI(mAuth.getCurrentUser());
            }
        };
    }
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
    public void open_login(){
        Intent open_login_activity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(open_login_activity);
    }
    public void open_postlogin(){
        Intent open_postlogin_activity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main_postlogin.class);
        startActivity(open_postlogin_activity);
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user){
        if (user  != null){
            open_postlogin();
            String gmail = user.getEmail();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, gmail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            open_login();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mAuthListener` no esta declarado, deberias declararlo arriba de tu `onCreate()`

```
  private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
  private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
  ...
```

Fijate que tenes un error de tipeo en `mAuthListner`, deberia ser `mAuthListener`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, eres un crack.